# How can I list categories by title and owner

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code currently.

```
<?php
$sectionsSide=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER by owner ASC");
while($sectionsSideRow=mysql_fetch_array($sectionsSide)) {
$url=strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $sectionsSideRow['title']));
echo '<li><a href="'.$cls->root().'/category/'.$url.'/">'.$sectionsSideRow['title'].'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

I want it to show by the owner, then by the title within the owner if that makes sense. How can I do this?

Comment: so we should just guess at your table's structure? I'd suggest reading up about `ORDER BY` clauses in SQL.

Comment: My table structure is as follows: id - title - description - image - owner. I'm using 'ORDER BY', but I need two clauses, and one to rule over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER by owner ASC, title ASC
```